# Hilbert 2-Class Field definition

Tags: class-field-theory

what is a Hilbert 2- class field?
As a Hilbert Class field of a number field K is the maximal unramified abelian extension, of K,

Comment: The Hilbert 2-class field is the maximal unramified abelian extension of $2$-power degree.

Answer (score 3):

Let be  $ K^{(1)}$ the Hilbert Class field of a number field $K$
and  $ K_p^{(1)}$ the Hilbert p-class field of $K$,  then $
K_p^{(1)}$ is exactly the sub extension of $ K^{(1)} / K$ which
corresponds (by Galois correspondence)  to Galois sub group of
$Gal( K^{(1)} / K)$ which is the
 direct product of all the $ q$-Sylow $(q \neq p)$ . so is the sub extension of $ K^{(1)} / K$  whose Galois group  $Gal( K_p^{(1)}/K)$ is
isomorphic to the p-Sylow of $Gal( K^{(1)} / K)$.